# Fixed work which means work hours remains unchanged irrespective of increase in duration when updated

Tags: team-management, ms-project, planning, scheduling, resource-planning

Using MS Project 2013, I would like to express the following situation. I have schedule/tasks set to fixed work which means work hours remains unchanged irrespective of the increase in duration when updated. However, when I change the duration it also changes the work hours. Can I stop this? Please advise me how to deal with this?

Comment: Check out [Microsoft's explanation of fixed work, units and duration.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-task-type-Project-uses-to-calculate-task-duration-5a421722-6618-451f-8d3c-0f7c45c1d2d2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US%20%22Microsoft's%20explanation%22%20on%20fixed%20work,%20duration%20and%20units) There's a table in there that will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing suggests your task is set to fixed utilization. Double check to make sure your task is set to fixed work.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply, the problem I facing now is unable to change the Task Type as Fixed work on Roll-up (WBS or Summary activity, (subsequent task is changed to Fixed Work), as I have assigned the resource to Roll-up activity level, not to all interim activities. advice me how change Task Type from fixed duration to Fixed work of Roll-up activity as it don't allow so. if you like I can forward you the schedule (plancoster@gmail.com).

Comment: I don't know how to fix your problem except to redo it correctly.  Delete what you did and rebuild your schedule, ensuring you use fixed work as task type.  And, I'd suggest loading resources at the lowest level of your schedule, not at the summary levels.